# Issue while checking data before loading in sql data loader

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the following code excerpt while loading data in Oracle DB using sql loader:

```
    "tran_code POSITION(238:239)," +
"frm_acct POSITION(247:265) \"TO_NUMBER(:frm_acct)\" NULLIF :frm_acct='*******************'," +
"to_acct POSITION(269:287)," +
```

It is giving an error on NULL IF i guess the issue is clear that i want to insert null when the data contains only asterisk otherwise convert to number and insert.

thanx in advance.

Comment: the question is not that clear, you want to convert the asterisk to number?

Comment: Is it possible that "TO_NUMBER(:frm_acct)" NULLIF :frm_acct='*******************'  should  read "NULLIF frm_acct='*******************'  TO_NUMBER(:frm_acct)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```
"decode(:YOUR_COL,'***************',NULL,TO_NUMBER(:YOUR_COL))"
```

However, I suggest better option in this scenarios is the "external table". 
Here's link for your reference :-
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm